# React-Loadable re-rendering causing input to lose focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, rerender, react-loadable

I'm having an issue where `react-loadable` is causing one of my input components to re-render and lose focus after a state update. I've done some digging and I can't find anyone else having this issue, so I think that I'm missing something here.

I am attempting to use `react-loadable` to dynamically include components into my app based on a theme that the user has selected. This is working fine.

> ./components/App

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

/**
 * Import Containers
 */
import AdminBar from '../../containers/AdminBar';
import AdminPanel from '../../components/AdminPanel';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './styles.css';

const App = ({ isAdmin, inEditMode, theme }) => {
    const MainContent = Loadable({
        loader: () => import('../../themes/' + theme.name + '/components/MainContent'),
        loading: () => (<div>Loading...</div>)
    });

    const Header = Loadable({
        loader: () => import('../../themes/' + theme.name + '/components/Header'),
        loading: () => (<div>Loading...</div>)
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {
                (isAdmin) ? <AdminBar
                                className='admin-bar'
                                inEditMode={inEditMode} /> : ''
            }
            <Header
                themeSettings={theme.settings.Header} />
            <div className='container-fluid'>
                <div className='row'>
                    {
                        (isAdmin && inEditMode) ? <AdminPanel
                                                    className='admin-panel'
                                                    theme={theme} /> : ''
                    }
                    <MainContent
                        inEditMode={inEditMode} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

> ./components/AdminPanel

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

import './styles.css';

const AdminPanel = ({ theme }) => {
    const ThemedSideBar = Loadable({
        loader: () => import('../../themes/' + theme.name +  '/components/SideBar'),
        loading: () => null
    });

    return (
        <div className='col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar'>
            <ThemedSideBar
                settings={theme.settings} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default AdminPanel;
```

This is what my `<ThemedSideBar />` components looks like:

> ./themes/Default/components/SideBar

```
import React from 'react';

import ThemeSettingPanel from '../../../../components/ThemeSettingPanel';
import ThemeSetting from '../../../../containers/ThemeSetting';

import './styles.css';

const SideBar = ({ settings }) => {
    return (
        <ThemeSettingPanel
            name='Header'>
            <ThemeSetting
                name='Background Color'
                setting={settings.Header}
                type='text'
                parent='Header' />
            <ThemeSetting
                name='Height'
                setting={settings.Header}
                type='text'
                parent='Header' />
        </ThemeSettingPanel>
    );
};

export default SideBar;
```

> ./components/ThemeSettingPanel

```
import React from 'react';
import { PanelGroup, Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';

const ThemeSettingPanel = ({ name, children }) => {
    return (
        <PanelGroup accordion id='sidebar-accordion-panelGroup'>
            <Panel>
                <Panel.Heading>
                    <Panel.Title toggle>{name}</Panel.Title>
                </Panel.Heading>
                <Panel.Body collapsible>
                    {children}
                </Panel.Body>
            </Panel>
        </PanelGroup>
    );
};

export default ThemeSettingPanel;
```

> ./containers/ThemeSetting

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { themeSettingChange } from '../App/actions';

import ThemeSetting from '../../components/ThemeSetting';

class ThemeSettingContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleOnChange(name, parent, value) {
        const payload = {
            name: name,
            parent,
            value: value
        };

        this.props.themeSettingChange(payload);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeSetting
                name={this.props.name}
                setting={this.props.setting}
                parent={this.props.parent}
                type={this.props.type}
                handleOnChange={this.handleOnChange} />
        );
    }
}

//----Redux Mappings----//
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    themeSettingChange: (value) => themeSettingChange(value)
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ThemeSettingContainer);
```

> ./component/ThemeSetting

```
import React from 'react';

import TextField from '../common/TextField';

import './styles.css';

const ThemeSetting = ({ name, setting, type, parent, handleOnChange }) => {
    return (
        <div className='row theme-setting'>
            <div className='col-xs-7'>
                {name}
            </div>
            <div className='col-xs-5'>
                {
                    generateField(type, setting, name, parent, handleOnChange)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

function generateField(type, setting, name, parent, handleOnChange) {
    const value = setting ? setting[name] : '';

    switch (type) {
        case 'text':
            return <TextField
                        value={value}
                        name={name}
                        parent={parent}
                        handleOnChange={handleOnChange} />;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

export default ThemeSetting;
```

> ./components/common/TextField

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';

const TextField = ({ value, name, parent, handleOnChange }) => {
    return (
        <FormControl
            type='text'
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) => {
                handleOnChange(name, parent, e.target.value);
            }} />
    );
};

export default TextField;
```

When a field inside of my Admin Panel is updated, a state change is triggered. It seems like this triggers `react-loadable` to re-render my `<ThemedSideBar />` components which destroys my input and creates a new one with the updated value. Has anyone else had this issue? Is there a way to stop `react-loadable` from re-rendering?

EDIT: [Here](https://github.com/NorianNyx/reactjs-lose-focus) is the requested link to the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: As per conversation in the comments, my apologies, I misread the question. Answer here is updated (original answer below updated answer)

### Updated answer

From looking at the [react-loadable docs](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#example), it appears that the Loadable HOC is intended to be called outside of a `render` method. In your case, you are loading `ThemedSideBar` in the render method of `AdminPanel`. I suspect that the change in your `TextEdit`'s input, passed to update your Redux state, and then passed back through the chain of components was causing React to consider re-rendering `AdminPanel`. Because your call to `Loadable` was inside the `render` method (i.e. `AdminPanel` is a presentational component), `react-loadable` was presenting a brand new loaded component every time React hit that code path. Thus, React thinks it needs to destroy the prior component to appropriately bring the components up to date with the new props.

This works:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

import './styles.css';

const ThemedSideBar = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('../../themes/Default/components/SideBar'),
  loading: () => null
});

const AdminPanel = ({ theme }) => {
    return (
        <div className='col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar'>
            <ThemedSideBar
                settings={theme.settings} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default AdminPanel;
```

### Original answer

It seems that your problem is likely related to the way you've built `TextField` and not `react-loadable`.

The `FormControl` is taking `value={value}` and the `onChange` handler as props. This means you've indicated it is a controlled (as opposed to [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)) component.

If you want the field to take on an updated value when the user types input, you need to propagate the change caught by your `onChange` handler and make sure it gets fed back to the value in the `value={value}` prop.

Right now, it looks like `value` will always be equal to `theme.settings.Height` or the like (which is presumably null/empty).

An alternative would be to make that FormControl an uncontrolled component, but I'm guessing you don't want to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually, `theme.settings.Height` is ultimately being updated by the `onChange` method in my reducer. I know this is working because the re-rendered component reflects the new state values. My reason for suspecting `react-loadable` is that if I load the component statically, I don't have the focus issue.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread "which destroys my input and creates a new one with the **updated** value". I will circle back when I have some time, likely tomorrow.

Comment: @NorianNyx I tried reproducing your issue locally - couldn't do it. When I set up a reducer to appropriately update the value, everything works fine (with react-loadable still there). Could you share a full public repo where I could reproduce this?

Comment: Thanks for the update! I will mark this as the correct answer. I will need to find a way to either circumvent this, or use a different library as I need access to the theme prop here to know which theme the user has selected. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Regarding themes - I don't have a lot of experience with appropriate paradigms for using CSS with React, but my hunch is that it is an anti-pattern to make entirely separate component libraries for styling reasons (if that's your intent behind "themes"). Maybe look at how UI frameworks like [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) handle this in their theme systems for alternative approach ideas, which should help resolve this issue

Comment: It's not so much CSS, even. My intention is the ability to create entire layouts with their own individual settings (think WordPress themes).

Comment: Ah ok. If you know which theme you want at build/deploy time, you could use [environment variables](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables) to make the path somewhat dynamic. But if you want them to be toggle-able in the running app, yeah you're right, seems like you'll want to work around the issue with `react-loadable`.